# Running different projects as modules in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

I have two different GAE projects project-1 and project-2. Each of these projects have their own queue.xml and cron.xml.
I am trying to deploy these two different projects as two independent modules in GAE under one App Engine project.
When i deploy project-1 and then deploy project-2, project-1 queue and cron entries are no more visible in the AppEngine and i could only see project-2 queues and cron entries.
Looks like the last deployed modules is disabling the previous module's queue and cron entries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the cron and queues are global to the App Engine project.

Hence, you need to merge your each module's queues.xml and cron.xml entries into one queue.xml file and one cron.xml. You will also need to use the right target: entries in order to specify the module in which the path for the cron can be found.

Then, you can upload these using update_cron and update_queues as the appcfg commands.